# How do Japanese call their friend's sister or brother?

Tags: politeness

Do you still call them as NeeChan/ NiiChan or OneeSan/ OniiSan? Or just their name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

兄ちゃん and 姉ちゃん are friendly way of saying. お兄さん and お姉さん are more polite than them. 
And When you call your friend's brother and sister, you say ～さんの姉ちゃん、お姉さん、兄ちゃん、お兄さん or just their name.